# Why does my menu refuse to show when I click the menu button?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to fix this menu functionality on my website for a while now. I am perplexed as to how it won't work. I've placed the script tags at the bottom of the body section, and the event listeners don't seem to be working right. I used a very janky version of this code earlier and it worked fine, but now when I plug that exact same code into this other project, it doesn't work at all.

```
const menu = document.getElementById("menu-active");
const menuBtn = document.getElementById("menu");

function menu(event){
    if (event.target != menu && event.target.parentNode != menu){
        menu.style.display == "none" ? menu.style.display = "block" : menu.style.display = "none";
    }
}

menuBtn.addEventListener("click", menu(event));
window.addEventListener("click", menu(event));
```

Comment: Please provide HTML part of this code

Comment: add your full code

Comment: You have given same variable name for function and also the constant which will cause error first. Please give a different name to any one of them.

Comment: because the HTML you are using does not match the JS code? or because you declare the js before the elements it uses? or because you declare the js before the elements it uses?